# OpenVPN autostart with systemd

Tags: vpn, systemd, openvpn

I enabled an openvpn globally by

```
systemctl enable openvpn@con.service
```

Which works well and I'm connected to my VPN after reboot. But once I suspend my laptop instead of rebooting, or simply lose the connection, I can't access to internet any more and have to do either a reboot or a `systemctl restart openvpn@con.service`

How can I reconnect automatically to my VPN?

An idea I have is to edit the openvpn@con.service manually and set a `Restart=always` and a `RestartSec=15`. But is that safe any longer? Won't my connection be interrupted? Is there a better solution?

This is what my con.conf looks like:

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote pw.openvpn.ipredator.se 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/IPredator.auth
auth-retry nointeract

ca [inline]

tls-client
tls-auth [inline]
ns-cert-type server

keepalive 10 30
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLSv1:!ADH:!SSLv2:!NULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!LOW:!MEDIUM:@STRENGTH
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix
passtos
verb 3

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
dummy
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
dummy
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: Odd that config is having OpenVPN exit. Could you check your log files (e.g., /var/log/daemon.log, /var/log/syslog, or /var/log/messages) and see if it gives a reason why? It should be logging a fair bit with `verb 3`.

Comment: I have only the following logs in /var/log: btmp  hp   old       wtmp      Xorg.2.log
cups  httpd   pacman.log      Xorg.0.log      Xorg.3.log
faillog  journal  pm-powersave.log   Xorg.0.log.old  Xorg.4.log
gdm  lastlog  speech-dispatcher  Xorg.1.log      Xorg.5.log

Comment: Odd. Wonder where your syslog is going. Which distro is this?

Comment: It's arch. I think journalctl should do this? http://nopaste.info/e0204b6c88.html

Comment: That looks like it could be a syslog. But I don't see any OpenVPN stuff in there.

Comment: Im getting a bit more used to journalctl. Ran a journalctl -u openvpn@IPredator.service and it gave me this (not beeing confused renamed IPredator with con.conf) http://pastebin.com/FNs38pZE i closed lid, waited, then made systemctl restart

Comment: Is the `Aug 22 18:26:07 arch systemd[1]: Stopping OpenVPN connection to IPredator...` when you had systemd restart it? It looks like OpenVPN was running before then. Maybe you just need to give it longer to re-establish the tunnel?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure OpenVPN not to exit when the connection goes down, and instead to reconnect (e.g., `ping-restart` instead of `ping-exit`). Also make sure you don't have things like `inactive` (exit on inactivity), or `single-session`.

You can also configure OpenVPN to keep the tunnel around, so traffic will potentially be sent insecurely with `persist-tun`. In addition, you may want to add firewall rules to ensure your traffic doesn't leak.

BTW: If you add the firewall rules, then you can safely have the connection interrupted.

Comment: Thanks, these are great ideas. Can you be a bit more detailed and teach me how to do so? I added my .conf file to the start-post.

Comment: No this will not work if the client ip changes, openvpn service will return "AUTH_FAILED" and just give up... keepalive and ping-restart does not have any effect over this unfortunelly...